# Is it OK to replace links to cplusplus.com with links to cppreference.com on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, hyperlinks

I have been replacing links to cplusplus.com with links to cppreference.com for a while. This behaviour has got some [attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/links-being-changed-to-cppreference-com) recently and I have been advised to continue only if consensus is reached here on meta.

I'm not familiar with the procedures of such proposals, so please bear with me :)

My motive for replacing the links and ultimately posting this question is that I believe that cppreference.com is simply a better reference. The general policy on SO is that edits improving the posts are encouraged, thus I think if we come to a consensus that the benefits of the change outweigh the disadvantages at least for some of the links, we could replace them.

Below are a summary of pros and cons. Feel free to add what I've missed :)

## Pros

- The quality of the content is higher (not always, but in general)
- The examples push 'better' programming practices, such as limited use of `using namespace std;`, `std::endl`, '#include ', etc.
- There's separate documentation for C and C++ versions of the C standard library.

  - [ The C99/C11 and C++11 standards have too many differences to put into a single article. ]
- The examples are live-editable.
- The content is free (cc-by-sa).
- No ads.

## Cons

- Some of the users simply don't like their answers being changed.

  - [ If an user reverts a change, it should be never re-applied ]
- cplusplus is better in some cases

  - [ The content of cppreference is publicly editable, thus any problems can be fixed as they are noticed ]

Comment: I've VTC as duplicate, since the original question is "Is this kind of activity acceptable on SO?". While you've fleshed that out further, I really don't think it's a separate question.

Comment: @Jim. I agree that it's kind-of duplicate, but for the purpose of building consensus, I think a question instead of an answer is better.

Comment: @jons34yp Don't worry, your activity is perfectly fine. `cplusplus.com` is simply not good enough to be included in a Stack Overflow answer. "Some users don't like their answers being changed"? Screw it!

Comment: From what people are saying, `cplusplus.com` is the equivalent of `w3schools.com`...

Comment: @jons34yp My comment was more a *"should there be other such situations in the future, then...."*. Not necessarily that this issue needs more consensus than already reached in the other question.

Comment: @jons34yp: don't go too fast on changing _all_ the links though. You're bumping posts left and right. Fix them as you see them, and do a bit of janitorial work once in a while, but don't just go editing everything at once.

Comment: @Mat  I'm not trying to edit everything at once, since there are ~10k links - it's not possible to finish in any reasonable time frame. Have I already exceeded the reasonable limits in your opinion?

Comment: Looks like you edited something like ~60 posts today already for this. That's a lot. There's no hard and fast rule for this, but since you're on a single topic that touches a single tag, that's probably a bit too eager. (Plus you'll get deathly bored of this, or completely OCD, neither of which is good.) There's no rush. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/379189/revisions) isn't such a good idea. You've edited a C++11 feature into a post from 2008. Probably fine in that case, but be careful with that.

Comment: @Mat My edit description probably wasn't appropriate, but isn't it good idea to update posts as time passes? Most of the time a new answer will have few upvotes and will not be read by most of the users. Moreover, usually the question is complex, and to create an useful answer most of the already existing answer would need to be copied. I think that minor edits that reflect the evolution of the language are beneficial. But maybe I missed some downsides?

Comment: That's a much more complex subject. In that specific case, indeed if you have a compiler that's up to date you shouldn't use `auto_ptr`. But notice that for people who don't (or can't for various reasons, that's still very common in the real world), that answer is now a bit less useful. So be careful when you do that not to lose information. Also take care about the question, some have specific version constraints, and introducing other things in the answers without properly stating the requirements is a problem.

Comment: Would you agree that something like 'If you can use C++11, then xxx is a good option' wouldn't hurt anybody?

Comment: @jons34yp: sure, but really, _slow down_. You're bumping way too many posts in a single tag, the front page has had your name all over it all day for people who have [C++] in their favorite tags, all for minor edits rather than new content. Seriously, you're doing too much too fast. (IMO of course.)

Comment: Sorry for me being an inconvenience. I figured out that editing all pages in my queue in a short period would be less of an annoyance than if my edits are dispersed across a longer timeframe. I still have ~15 pages to edit, but after that you won't see me for a long time :)

Comment: Why shouldn't we use `std::endl`?

Comment: @ColeJohnson `std::endl` is discouraged because it is equivalent to `'\n'` plus `std::flush`, the latter of which is a unnecessary pessimization in almost absolute majority of examples and day-to-day usage in general.

Comment: @jons34yp On Windows, isn't it equal to `\r\n`, not `\n`?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes and no. The call is indeed results in `\n` being written to cout (see the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)), but that character will converted to `\r\n` just before being written out to the disk or console. This is done by the codecvt machinery of the underlying stream buffer (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf)).