# Why would anybody edit my answer to change links to cppreference?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, answers

Today my answer was edited and a link from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) was changed to cppreference.com. The edit comment was "use better reference".

I read this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/links-being-changed-to-cppreference-com), which was provided by the editor.

The problem is that the word "better" is extremely relative. Better for someone is worse for another. I absolutely don't care about cppreference.com and cplusplus.com, but changing links to another website, just because you prefer that one, is wrong. I don't think one is better than the other, but I edited it back to cplusplus. People, don't try to push your opinions onto others.

Imagine [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) is my favorite cpp reference. Why would anybody edit the link to another reference?

Answer (score 14):

> Why would anybody edit my answer to change links to cppreference

To improve your answer. That's why people edit. They try to improve the content they see. You can throw all your "opinion pushing" - or whatever other interpretation you like - at it, the fact is that the user who edited your answer tried to be helpful.

As [has been discussed in an earlier Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/links-being-changed-to-cppreference-com) there are those within the C++ community who don't think highly of the information provided by cplusplus.com.

> Imagine cplusplus.com is my favorite cpp reference. Why would anybody edit the link another reference?

With some of the concerns expressed in that question, the matter of a "favourite" reference moves away from favouritism, and goes towards reliability and correctness. And that would answer your question. Why would they change it? Again, to improve the content. Adding a more reliable resource is of course always welcome.

Now, if you disagree with the idea that one resource is better than the other, or that your favourite has significant flaws, by all means go and express that in the other question. State your case and the community can have a look. Or if you don't see where your favourite is flawed, by all means ask them what the problem really is. (Or perhaps you can even ask that in the [C++ Lounge chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), if they welcome such questions. I don't really know).

But in general, editing is done to improve content. And without any clear malicious intent, all we can assume is that the editor is trying to be helpful, and they should be thanked for it. Still think the edit is not a good one? Then roll it back. That's all.

Comment: Well, There is always a rollback option. Good answer btw.

Comment: I get it, I may have sounded a bit aggressive but my point is that opinion based edits may actually make answers worse. My point is not about those two websites but generally about everything on this website(s). The answer about `cppreference` is also biased. I am new in this community and in programming in general. We are all here to help and to get help but opinion based answers may actually make more harm, so it is better to edit based on facts or to have a really strong explanation.

Comment: *"opinion based edits may actually make answers worse"* ... they may. But then the first point of action should be to verify if it's truly only a opinion based edit.